# Reverse Engineering a function based on inputs and outputs

Tags: functional-analysis, random-functions

I have a function that takes a whole number and outputs four values. For now I am only worried about matching the first 2 outputs. What is the best way to do this? I would use regression but due to the output using mod I believe I would just get the mean and it wouldn't  match.
The first value is always between 11 and 30. The second is 2, 3, or 4. The third is between 10 and 24. The fourth is between 5 and 20.

example values:

```
480 -> 25, 3, 19, 18
481 -> 20, 4, 20, 11
482 -> 19, 2, 16, 17
483 -> 29, 4, 14, 13
484 -> 28, 3, 11, 15
487 -> 27, 3, 11, 11
512 -> 27, 3, 11, 19
971 -> 19, 4, 24, 18

Here are some values that I haven't finished computing the first value but I know the range its in
IN -> N, A, F, T
485 -> (26-30), 4, 11, 16
486 -> (21-25), 3, 18, 15
488 -> (26-30), 2, 13, 18
489 -> (16-20), 2, 21, 7
490 -> (16-20), 3, 10, 13
491 -> (26-30), 2, 24, 10
492 -> (26-30), 2, 22, 13
493 -> (16-20), 2, 10, 18
494 -> (16-20), 4, 22, 16
495 -> (21-25), 3, 20, 18
496 -> (11-15), 3, 22, 6
497 -> (21-25), 2, 12, 17
498 -> (26-30), 2, 13, 20
499 -> (21-25), 4, 17, 10
500 -> (26-30), 3, 24, 10
501 -> (11-15), 2, 23, 11
502 -> (21-25), 2, 19, 19
503 -> (21-25), 2, 18, 13
```

Comment: This is very vague.  Without knowing something about the function(s) in question, there's really not a lot to be said.  These values look pretty random. Have you got any model in mind for the function(s)?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your input and output are restricted to such numbers?

Comment: I don't know anything about the function other then what I list above. I don't have a model which is why I decided to ask here. Not an expert just know my goal.

Comment: The input is not restricted. you can input any value. I have just only calculated some so far. As for output restrictions. the first is representing a name, names comes in sets of 5. the second represents an attribute. so the exact number matter less for the first two and rather the pattern but if you get the pattern you can get the number but just adding or subtracting so. The third is a select floor which can range from 10 to 24. And the fourth is time which can be 5mins to 20 mins